# Broken route in Laravel depending on where it's defined in the file

Tags: laravel

I have those routes defined in my `routes/web.php` :

```
Route::get('references/', 'referenceController@index')
Route::get('references/{reference}', 'referenceController@show')
Route::get('references/create', 'referenceController@create')
```

Like that, the `references/create` route goes to a 404 page.

If I put this route one line before, everything works fine :

```
Route::get('references/', 'referenceController@index')
Route::get('references/create', 'referenceController@create')
Route::get('references/{reference}', 'referenceController@show')
```

Then it is obviously because of the `{reference}` part in my route, right? But as I wanted to filter the reference perfectly, I've put a pattern in `RouteServiceProvider.php`. This pattern should check that my reference is a well-formed UUID :

`Route::pattern('reference', '[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{10}');`

Miles away from the word "create", which doesn't match the pattern.

Do you know why my route is going to a 404 page depending on its position in the file?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it with the same routes and pattern, but I don't get the 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Laravel is supposed to work. It isn't very clear in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers) though I'll admit.

> ### Supplementing Resource Controllers
>
> If you need to add additional
>   routes to a resource controller beyond the default set of resource
>   routes, you should define those routes before your call to
>   Route::resource; otherwise, the routes defined by the resource method
>   may unintentionally take precedence over your supplemental routes:
>
> `Route::get('photos/popular', 'PhotoController@method');`
>
> `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');`

This is also true if you are defining non-resource routes as you noted in your example. This is because it will try to pass `"create"` as the id of the `reference` parameter in the route which of course is not valid.

---

#### Rule of Thumb

When defining routes that have the same number of url segments, always define the route that does not have a parameter variable first. The routes file will go top-down and find the first route that matches the current request.

Comment: Exactly what I thought but couldn't find a viable explanation, thanks. Quite a shame the pattern doesn't act as a guardian at this point :-/